# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference error

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a song object to insert into an object based array list (for a music player app). The song object should contain properties album, artist, title, etc.

However, he app crashes when I run the program, and I get this error in the log cat.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Here is my main class:

```
private ListView listView1;

// A list of song objects
private ArrayList<Song> songObectList;

// Song object will be passed to SongObjectList
private Song songObject = new Song();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Add song objects to songObjectList
    getMusic();

    // Initialize adapter
    SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, songObectList);

    // Initialize listView
    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // Initialize header
    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);

    // Add header to listView
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);

    // Add adapter to listView
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);


private void getMusic() {

    // Set URI
    Uri contentURI = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    // Set projection parameter for getContentResolver query
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
    };

    // Run getContentResolver query
    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            contentURI, projection, null, null, null
    );

    // Set song object properties 
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            songObject.album = mCursor.getString(0);
            songObject.artist = mCursor.getString(1);
            songObject.title = mCursor.getString(2);
            songObject.data = mCursor.getString(3);
            songObject.duration = mCursor.getString(4);

            songObectList.add(songObject);

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    mCursor.close();

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where do you initialize the songObectList.

Try replacing

```
// A list of song objects
private ArrayList<Song> songObectList;
```

with

```
// A list of song objects
private ArrayList<Song> songObectList = new ArrayList<Song>();
```

Comment: Thanks. The whole program just worked like magic. Stupid question: why do arrays lists need to be initialized? Do all new object need to be initialized?

Comment: Every object definition needs to be initialized, that is, instantiated, before calling any of its non-static methods.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialised your songObjectList. Do:

```
private ArrayList<Song> songObectList = new ArrayList<>();
```